# Why can't I call a static method in the constructor of a class?

Tags: java, methods, static, constructor, undefined

obviously my Java Pause was too long...

I have the following classes:

```
public class TimeLine {

    public static final String TIME_LINE_DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";


    public TimeLine(Context context, LinearLayout layout)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;           
    }

    // some methods and stuff

    public static Date getDateFromString(String dateString)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_LINE_DATE_FORMAT);
        try {
            return s.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the parsing of a String to a Date quite often, that's why I wanted to have this function only 1 time & static.

I try to access it like this:

```
public class TrackedValue {

    private double value;
    private String unit;
    private Date date;

    public TrackedValue()
    {       
    }

    public TrackedValue(Date date, String unit, double value)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TrackedValue(String dateString, String unit, double value)
    {      
        this.date = TimeLine.getDateFromString(dateString); //Here's the error
        this.unit = unit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // some getters and setters here

}
```

This brings me the error:
*The method getDateFromString(String) is undefined for the type timeline*

Err... why?

Comment: My guess: you are not referring to the `TimeLine` you think you are.

Comment: Or may be `TimeLine` is not *compiled*

Comment: The way it is TimeLine is not compiling. There are no other issues with the code than that. Calling the static method is fine.

Comment: What does the import statement in The TrackedValue.java file look like for the Timeline package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Why can't I call a static method in the constructor of a class?`

***You can call static method in your constructor*** and no one can stop you unless you don't have access to the method like access modifier restriction.

There could be problem in your `import` statement .Please check `TimeLine`  class is there or is this imported correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your imports section.

Is YOUR timeline class referenced there or is there another from some other jar you have imported to your application?

Comment: The TrackedValue imports look like this: `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.util.Log;
import at.antonio.mytracker.graph.TimeLine;` ... so it is mine. It's just in another package

Answer (score 1):

dah... TimeLine was not saved and therefore not compiled... I feel a little bit stupid now :-/
Thanks guys!